# iOS 8.1.2 IPA Unsigned IPA Creation for Jailbroken device?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, provisioning-profile, ios8.1

I need to create a IPA with out Developer account and Provisional profile.
I have done this before in Xcode 5 by made a little change from Xcode by using [this](http://initcodes.blogspot.in/2014/01/build-unsigned-ipa-without-developer.html) instruction

GoTo /Applications then right click Xcode.app and click "Show Package Contents"

Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/SDKSettings.plist

find  and change its value from YES to NO. Save the file.

**But it's not work for Xcode 6.1 and iOS 8.1**

Also i have jailbreak my device.

If any one create unsigned IPA in Xcode for iOS 8.1 please provide me a solution.